# reordenar un archivo CSV usando pandas (Python)

Tags: python, excel, pandas, csv, group-by

**El objetivo de este código es tomar información mezclada de un archivo CSV y reordenarla en forma horizontal para luego guardar esos mismos datos ya ordenados en otro archivo de Excel**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Para esto el código trata de separar la información del archivo utilizando un groupby pero al momento de correr obtengo un mensaje de error**:

```
df.groupby(['Variable', 'Tiempo'], as_index=False).sum()
```

File "C:\Pyto\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 6717, in groupby

```
return DataFrameGroupBy(
```

File "C:\Pyto\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\groupby.py", line 560, in **init**

```
grouper, exclusions, obj = get_grouper(
```

File "C:\Pyto\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\grouper.py", line 811, in get_grouper

```
raise KeyError(gpr)
```

KeyError: 'Variable'

**al investigar descubrí que la función groupby a veces genera fallos manejando archivos de Excel pero no se si ese sea el caso en este código, también intente con otras sintaxis para esa linea pero ninguna me ha funcionado, anexo el código mas abajo**

Archivo CSV: https://mega.nz/file/K8JihDZK#-xh-WfaPc7tX6OPy52zPg9CEurhQyFPx01ukA6yK1ek

Codigo obtenido de: https://buhardillaalquimista.home.blog/2020/08/27/como-utilizar-ficheros-csv-con-pandas-python/

Comment: Por favor agrega una parte del csv como texto

Comment: Tiempo Valor
Tiempo 1 Valor sensor 1
Tiempo 1 Valor sensor 2
Tiempo 1 Valor sensor 3
Tiempo 2 Valor sensor 1
Tiempo 2 Valor sensor 2
Tiempo 2 Valor sensor 3
Tiempo 3 Valor sensor 1
Tiempo 3 Valor sensor 2
Tiempo 3 Valor sensor 3
Tiempo 4 Valor sensor 1
Tiempo 4 Valor sensor 2
Tiempo 4 Valor sensor 3

Comment: esta el texto del csv en las tablas de arriba

Comment: Esta como imagen, en caso quiera probar tu codigo tendré que transcribir todo

Comment: no lo puedo colocar en el post, lo subi a mega https://mega.nz/file/K8JihDZK#-xh-WfaPc7tX6OPy52zPg9CEurhQyFPx01ukA6yK1ek

Comment: Me doy cuenta que no has puesto el código, eso es esencial para saber cual cual fue tu error, puede que el código del enlace este correcto pero talvez tu cometiste un error, te recomiendo leer [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) y luego  [editas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/455211/edit) tu pregunta

Comment: Lo que te dije servirá para que obtengas ayuda rápidamente, ya que facilita las cosas, aquí hay miles de personas que dedican su tiempo valioso a ayudar a los demás, por eso hay que tener consideración con ellos

Comment: Creo que para pasarlo a horizontal necesitas usar `stack` y luego lo dejas como estaba usando `unstack`. Mira en google sobre ello.